# Comparing n records with other records in ES

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, comparison

I have a elastic search index with 100 million records, i want to compare each record in this index with every other record, how to do this efficiently and fast? Brute Force approach would have the complexity O(n^2)? How can i distribute the work, multithreading would work but even that is slow, it takes around 1 hour to compare 100k objects.

Comment: Are you comparing it for sorting or is it the business requirement? If it is sorting,algorithms like quicksort can be applied here.

Comment: @MaulikDoshi this is not for sorting

Comment: Than I think you may go for parallel programming. You can find about it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350459/parallel-programming-in-java

Comment: Or you may use hashing for comparison. I don't know whether it will give better performance or not.

Comment: threads will not work, i have already added that in the description

Comment: I am not talking about concurrent programming. I am talking about parallel programming. You may create a cluster or grid as your computation requirement is very high.